# Can I use a Query ID as a filter in a POST request in Azure DevOps?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I am working with Azure DevOps Services and trying to retrieve work items using the Work Item Query Language (WIQL). I noticed that the GET request utilizes a Query ID to fetch the results of a saved query:

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/wit/wiql/{id}?api-version=7.1-preview.2
```

I also have a POST request that I use to execute a new WIQL query:

```
POST https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/wit/wiql?api-version=7.1-preview.2

{
  "query": "Select [System.Id], [System.Title], [System.State] From WorkItems Where [System.WorkItemType] = 'Risk' AND [State] <> 'Closed' AND [State] <> 'Removed' order by [Microsoft.VSTS.Common.Priority] asc, [System.CreatedDate] desc"
}
```

Is there a way to incorporate the Query ID as a filter condition within the POST request as well?
I want to be able to execute a saved query and possibly apply additional filters or operations to the results.
Any advice or examples would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to incorporate the Query ID as a filter condition within the POST request as well?

I am afraid that the WIQL Post Rest API doesn't support adding the Query ID as a filter.

For a workaround, you can use Rest API: [Queries - Get](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/queries/get?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1&tabs=HTTP#queryexpand) to get the saved Query WIQL filter.

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{org}/{Project}/_apis/wit/queries/{query}?$expand=clauses&api-version=6.1-preview.2
```

For example:  check the **wiql** field in the response.

[image]

Then you can copy the wiql content of the saved query and add additional filters to the wiql filter.

Finally, you can use the new WIQL Filter content as the request body of the Post WIQL Rest API.